# Non javascript link to Live Chat

Tags: liveagent

We have a requirement to emebed a link to Live Chat within an article.  The article cannot contain Javascript.  I'm pretty sure this can't be done, but just throwing this out to see if anyone has ever done this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe its possible simply because the button is a JS action, however, is the button being referenced from a Community? If so, could you satisfy the requirement but just routing the user(s) to the Community page the button is found on?